# what does this mean "Table "total_bikeshare" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table)." in sql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

I am trying the combine 12 months datasets into one table, i tried using CREATE TABLE function but i am getting below error-

Table "total_bikeshare" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table).
Please help this understand what this means?

Comment: The error message must be citated completely and precisely, without any edition. And SQL statement which causes it must be provided completely too.

Comment: Why is this tagged bigquery?

Comment: Can you share more details, like the query you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same data set and the one that did it for me is to change the format you used for the view as `folder_name.data_set.view_name`.

Same as this. `gothic-victor-368405.trip_data.trip_data_2022`